# Finding hooks Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hook

I know there are lists of hooks for WordPress like --> http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook

But if I want to find hooks for a plugin like WC Vendors there is a much shorter list of hooks on their website.

Are 'do_action' and 'apply filter' functions the only thing we can modify?
If given a class like --> https://github.com/wcvendors/wcvendors/blob/master/classes/admin/class-product-meta.php#L10, is there any way to modify it?

Are we limited to the do_action hooks or is there a way to modify other areas as well? Can we use the WordPress hooks to hook into the WC Vendors plugin as well?

Comment: You can inherit the class and override it .You can also override templates and add your own hook and filters . A lot  of thing can be done.

Comment: Once we've inherited the class we'd save the new file into the plugin folder or into the child theme, correct? Also to access the files we'd use pointers and such right, not create hooks?

Comment: you can create hook, when ever you are generating html from your method , there is a chance you can create a hook.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly you should try to accomplish any task with hooks, but some tasks are just not possible without actually modifying the actual code. But we all know its not good to modify core code, as all changes disappear after an update. So instead of modifying a class, you can extend it. You can override the current features and also add new ones. Extending a class is as easy as using a relavant hook in functions.php and then extending it in the same file or requiring it from another file. Here is an official [tutorial](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/shipping-method-api/) on how to add a new shipping method to the woocommerce shipping class.

Sometimes you dont even need all the hooks, you just need to find the ones that are running on a specific page. For this you can use the code below to list all the current hooks.

```
$debug_tags = array();
add_action( 'all', function ( $tag ) {
    global $debug_tags;
    if ( in_array( $tag, $debug_tags ) ) {
        return;
    }
    echo "<pre>" . $tag . "</pre>";
    $debug_tags[] = $tag;
} );
```

Or you can use this plugin "[simply show hooks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simply-show-hooks/)"which is really helpful while development as it gives you an idea of where each hook is being triggered on the page.

Comment: "Extending a class is as easy as using a relavant hook in functions.php and then extending it in the same file or requiring it from another file"... How would we add a relevant hook? And by extending it in the same file you mean the core, correct. It can be added into the child theme as well, right?

Comment: What i meant by using a relevant hook was, lets say if you are extending the checkout shipping class, then you should first create a new plugin and you can then use hooks like woocommerce_checkout_shipping to hook into the parent class, but using a hook is not always necessary. Secondly what i meant by extending in the same file was to extend it in the same plugin file or functions file. You should never make any changes to the core files.

Comment: This snippet worked great for me. I needed to find a hook on the checkout page that I did not know the name of and it worked fine. Just had to do some digging. It's been a couple years, not sure if there's a better solution but this works right out of the box.